# Perl glob one liner

Tags: perl, glob

Im working in a perl one liner to invert the contents of my file contents or perform operations, I was able to generate the script and one liner, but this one liner only works by entering file by file.

```
perl -i -ne '$a=reverse $_;print "$a\n"' <filename>
```

I want to change my one liner to get input from a range of files but when i do:

```
perl -i -ne '$a=reverse $_;print "$a\n"' | ls -al
```

I just get screen output of `ls -al`
Not sure how to proceed.

Thanks

Comment: By doing "perl ... | ls -la", you exec perl and feed the output to "ls -la" which ignores STDIN, and just prints directory listing.

Comment: You may want to look at `rev`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use xargs(1):

```
ls | xargs perl -i -ne '$a=reverse $_;print "$a\n"'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -nle '$c=reverse;print $c' * .*
```